# Can't get Contains to work in Linq query where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
        List<Guid> toBeFilteredCarIds = new List<Guid>();
        toBeFilteredCarIds.Add(new Guid("4cc70c3a-405c-4a5c-b2cd-0429a5bc06ef"));

        var cars = ef.Cars
            .Include("CarProfile.Option.OptionType")
            .Where(c => c.CarStatusId == 1);

        cars.Join(ef.CarProfile,
            t1 => t1.CarId,
            t2 => t2.Car.CarId,
            (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 }).Where(o => o.t2.IsActive == true).Select(o => o.t1);

        var filteredCars = cars.ToList().Where(u => toBeFilteredCarIds.Contains(u.CarId));
```

the above code is trying to get list of Cars, where CarProfile is active, and the CarId is in the toBeFilteredCarIds list.

However as you can see in the last line, I am doing .ToList() first and then doing Where clause to filter by the CarIds.

This obviously will get all cars first from DB, and then do the filter. Which is very expensive.

I have tried the way others have suggested on other answers:

```
        List<Guid> toBeFilteredCarIds = new List<Guid>();
        toBeFilteredCarIds.Add(new Guid("4cc70c3a-405c-4a5c-b2cd-0429a5bc06ef"));

        var cars = ef.Cars
            .Include("CarProfile.Option.OptionType")
            .Where(c => toBeFilteredCarIds.Contains(c.CarId) && c.CarStatusId == 1);

        cars.Join(ef.CarProfile,
            t1 => t1.CarId,
            t2 => t2.Car.CarId,
            (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 }).Where(o => o.t2.IsActive == true).Select(o => o.t1);

        var filteredCars = cars.ToList();
```

but that's not working for me, it gives me this error:

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(System.Guid)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

I can see on stackoverflow, many have marked as answered the above approach:

```
.Where(c => toBeFilteredCarIds.Contains(c.CarId)
```

but its not working for me.

By they way am using: VS2008, EF 3.5, and I have got **using System.Data.Entity;** in my using statements.

*"Include" used above is important, as I need to get everything before hand, as there will be huge set of loops reading the data afterwords.*

Comment: Can you perhaps try using `string` instead of `Guid`?

Comment: tried ... doesn't works

Comment: Contains is a little funny about comparing classes sometimes (which it does as part of Contains). I would suggest creating an IEqualityComparer to pass into one of the overloads of contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Contains` on `IEnumerable` wasn't added until 4.0 so if you're stuck in 3.5 you'll need to do something like unrolling the values before sending the query.

Look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 3.5 doesn't support Contains, you can use a Dynamic Linq Library which would allow you generate your where clause using a string.  That way, you wouldn't have to fiddle with all the Expression lingo.

Available on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/.

Your Where clause would look something like this:

```
.Where("CarStatusId=1 AND (CarId=1 OR CarId=2 OR CarId=3"))
```

You'd just have to generate that string based on your toBeFilteredCarIds list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Any()`. Not as elegant as `Contains()`, but it does the job in .NET 3.5:

```
.Where(c => toBeFilteredCarIds.Any(g => g == c.CarId) && c.CarStatusId == 1);
```